# Silverlight 4 - how to skip building localized resources at Bin / Debug

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

Is it possible to skip building localized resources at Bin / Debug foler?

There are many folders for languages but my application work only in English and these folders aren't required. I think it could speed up build process. Right now this application contains about 40 different projects and building in on VS2010 takes ages...